# password authentication failed while trying to connect into my docker database

Tags: docker, psql

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e37NbhSm56o&t=303s) and the guy uses docker with postgres which I've never used honestly. I created a docker-compose.yml file with the following fields:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: actix
      POSTGRES_DB: actix
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: actix
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

and tried running `docker-compose up -d` and everything is fine until now. When I try to run `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U actix actix`  to access it and put the password (which I've tried doing multiple times so I'm 100% sure it's not a typo) I get this error:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "actix"
```

I've tried googling the error but there is not a unique fix apparently.

What I've tried so far:

- checking if I've messed up the local port by using `docker ps`
- changing version image
- checking if I have psql (I have psql (PostgreSQL) 14.1)
- tried connecting inside the docker using `docker exec -it "name of the docker" bash` and `psql -U actix` and it does in fact work.

Hope I was clear enough, if I left something out I will provide any additional info you need.

**Edit**: I've tried creating another postgres container to try and connect and it does work.

I've also tried using the gitbash cli and it doesn't work so that must be a windows problem of some sort.

**Edit 2** I solved it. Stopping the PostgreSQL service did the trick.

Comment: Thank you for posting the Edit 2.