# password authentication failed for user "root", postgresSQL and docker

Tags: javascript, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to connect to my database using postgres on docker but it says that the password authentication failed.

My code:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'mycontacts',
});

client.connect();
```

docker command to start the postgres container:

```
docker run --name postg -e POSTGRES_USER=root2 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root2 -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and share the container configuration, i.e. either the `docker run ...` command or the `docker-compose.yml` used to start the container.

Comment: just did it. the docker-compose.yml i don't know where it is and haven't changed or created it.

Comment: In the `docker run ...`-command, we set the `POSTGRES_USER` and the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to `root2`. Hence, we need to set `user` and `password` in the code to `root2` as well.

Comment: still the same error...

Comment: delete the volume, it wont recreate root if the db already exists in the volume. Also make sure you use the same in your code and in the env vars. Currently they are different.

Comment: i had postgres install on my pc and it seems that it was it. I uninstalled it and now i made it. Thanks anyway for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another Postgres container to try and connect and it will work.
Else. [password authentication failed while trying to connect into my docker database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022945/password-authentication-failed-while-trying-to-connect-into-my-docker-database)

Comment: Please read: [Can I answer if I'm not sure?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370133/can-i-answer-if-im-not-sure)

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being the postgres that i had installed on my pc.

I uninstalled it and now its working!